# Definition of onto for linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

I had a question ask the following:
"A linear transformation is onto if and only if the columns of its standard matrix form a generating set for its range."

To me that seems true but the answer was false. Could someone clarify why this is false? I thought a linear transformation is onto if for all R^n then there is a a range of images R^m where:

$T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$.

The way to go about verifying whether the range of the matrix in question is $\mathbb{R}^m$ is to find the generated set through reduced row echelon form. If the number of columns in the generated set equals m than our set spans $\mathbb{R}^m$ and hence the range $\mathbb{R}^m$ of our images(Since the range of a linear transformation equals the span of the columns of its standard
matrix.)

Answer (score 2):

A linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^m$ is onto (surjective) is its range (image) is $\Bbb R^m$ which is equivalent to "the columns of its standard matrix form a generating set of $\Bbb R^m$".